# JDK for Ghidra give me Error: "Could not find or load main class LaunchSupport"

Tags: java, ghidra

I downloaded JDK 15 for my windows 10 64 bit pc and put the environment variable JAVA-HOME correct and the PATH also. This give me in cmd:

```
    C:\Users\patpin>java -version
    java version "15.0.2" 2021-01-19
    Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 15.0.2+7-27)
    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 15.0.2+7-27, mixed mode, sharing)
```

When I start Ghidra (even as admin) I get:

```
    Error: Could not find or load main class LaunchSupport
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: LaunchSupport
    Error: Could not find or load main class LaunchSupport
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: LaunchSupport
    Error: Could not find or load main class LaunchSupport
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: LaunchSupport
```

Failed to find a supported JDK.  Please refer to the Ghidra Installation Guide's Troubleshooting section.

Comment: Use a version of java supported by the application. Read the documentation.

Comment: I changed version to: openjdk version "11.0.10" 2021-01-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.10+9)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.10+9, mixed mode). I still get the same error. Path and JAVA_HOME is also changed.

Comment: What is the Ghidra version you are currently using?

Comment: Ghidra 9.2.2 used now.

Comment: Production or Development version?

Comment: probably ghidra_9.2.2_PUBLIC_20201229.zip was downloaded at https://ghidra-sre.org/releaseNotes_9.2.2.html, but not shure. Where can I find it.

Comment: It was 9.2.2 production version.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this issue can be solved by updating the **lunch.properties** file.

First, try to fullfil their minimal requirements. According to ghidra's documentation

- Current Ghidra 9.2.2 need Java 11 64-bit Runtime and Development Kit (JDK)
- So, it is better to install java 11 64 bit.

If ghidra fails to locate the jdk, then force it by-

- To launch with a specific version of Java, set the JAVA_HOME_OVERRIDE property in the support/launch.properties file. If this property is set to an incompatible version of Java, Ghidra will revert to automatically locating a compatible version.

Comment: I installed 64 bit jdk-11.0.10 (jdk-11.0.10_windows-x64_bin.exe) and put in environment AND launch.properties unther the ..-overrride: the path C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.10\ ... Still the same problem.

Comment: in cmd-> java -version gives: ...java version "11.0.10" 2021-01-19 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.10+8-LTS-162)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.10+8-LTS-162, mixed mode)...

Comment: my user environment gives: java version "11.0.10" 2021-01-19 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.10+8-LTS-162)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.10+8-LTS-162, mixed mode)

Comment: my system variables: PATH: C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath

Comment: Did you add bin? Like C:\Program Files\....\jdk-11.0.10\bin . If not then add it.

Comment: For user var JAVA_HOME or     system var Path or     at JAVA-HOME_OVERRIDE in launch.properties?

Comment: Is this problem still exist? Then run it at debug mode. Go and run support/ghidraDebug.bat file. Read and locate the log files. If possible send it, it helps to figure out the problem.

Comment: Where are the log files located? (And how to view?)

Comment: when you run at debugging mode, a cmd prompt will appear. You will find details like log location, jdk version there.

Comment: When I run Ghidradebug.bat I receive also the same error message saying: Error: Could not find or load main class LaunchSupport
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: LaunchSupport
Error: Could not find or load main class LaunchSupport
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: LaunchSupport
Error: Could not find or load main class LaunchSupport
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: LaunchSupport

Failed to find a supported JDK.  Please refer to the Ghidra Installation Guide's Troubleshooting section.
Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: my version is: java version "11.0.10" 2021-01-19 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.10+8-LTS-162)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.10+8-LTS-162, mixed mode)

Answer (score 0):

This may be because you're using the release from github, and these releases are not built and only contain the source code.
Source: https://github.com/NationalSecurityAgency/ghidra/issues/2872

To fix the issue, you can try download ghidra from here https://www.ghidra-sre.org/